# View local NPM packages that depend on package X

Tags: node.js, npm

I am getting some `node-gyp` warnings for a particular NPM package, in this case the package is "get-cursor-position". I would like to find out which packages in my local node_modules directory depend on this package. (This might *not* be easy to do).

If I run:

```
$ npm view get-cursor-position
```

I get:

```
{ name: 'get-cursor-position',
  description: 'Get the cursor\'s current position in your terminal.',
  'dist-tags': { latest: '1.0.3' },
  versions: 
   [ '0.0.1',
     '0.0.2',
     '0.0.4',
     '0.0.5',
     '1.0.0',
     '1.0.1',
     '1.0.2',
     '1.0.3' ],
  maintainers: [ 'bubkoo <bubkoo@163.com>' ],
  time: 
   { modified: '2016-11-01T02:36:07.728Z',
     created: '2016-03-05T03:42:31.517Z',
     '0.0.1': '2016-03-05T03:42:31.517Z',
     '0.0.2': '2016-03-07T00:35:36.627Z',
     '0.0.4': '2016-03-10T07:21:21.364Z',
     '0.0.5': '2016-03-10T07:25:04.846Z',
     '1.0.0': '2016-04-16T08:11:34.546Z',
     '1.0.1': '2016-06-03T15:57:55.767Z',
     '1.0.2': '2016-06-13T14:19:32.966Z',
     '1.0.3': '2016-11-01T02:36:07.728Z' },
  homepage: 'https://github.com/bubkoo/get-cursor-position',
  keywords: [ 'terminal', 'console', 'cursor', 'position', 'ansi', 'escape' ],
  repository: 
   { type: 'git',
     url: 'git+https://github.com/bubkoo/get-cursor-position.git' },
  author: 'bubkoo <bubkoo.wy@gmail.com>',
  bugs: { url: 'https://github.com/bubkoo/get-cursor-position/issues' },
  license: 'MIT',
  readmeFilename: 'README.md',
  version: '1.0.3',
  main: 'index.js',
  scripts: 
   { test: 'echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1',
     install: 'node-gyp rebuild' },
  gypfile: true,
  gitHead: '56d403bb0e554532d17c403c47421ce8d2db2dec',
  dist: 
   { shasum: '0e41d60343b705836a528d69a5e099e2c5108d63',
     tarball: 'https://registry.npmjs.org/get-cursor-position/-/get-cursor-position-1.0.3.tgz' },
  directories: {} }
```

I believe npm view will just look up the remote data for the package, I am happy to use the aggregate data on NPM showing all the packages that  depend on `get-cursor-position`, and I can do some manual work on my end to compare with local packages.

I also tried:

```
npm ls foo
```

In my case, I tried:

```
npm ls suman-events
```

and it didn't seem to pick up what I expected it to pick up. I would have expected it to pick up "suman-example-reporter" in my case =>

As you can see in the image below, "suman-example-reporter" is a direct dependency in my project (it's in package.json) and suman-example-reporter depends on "suman-events" (and "suman-events" is in package.json as well, because it's also a direct dependency of my project).

[image]

Anyone know how to do this right?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/browse/depended/get-cursor-position

Comment: Does `npm ls get-cursor-position` work? I don’t remember.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ryan suggested in the comments, [`npm ls <package>`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls) will show the dependency tree relating to the specified package, so you can see which packages directly/indirectly require it.

For example, if you install `rimraf`, `once` is a dependency, and you can view which package causes it to be installed with:

```
$ npm ls once
yourpackage@1.0.0 /path/to/pkg
└─┬ rimraf@2.5.4
  └─┬ glob@7.1.1
    └── once@1.4.0
```

Hence, you can see that `once` was installed because `glob` requires it, and `rimraf` (which I specified in my `package.json`) depended on `glob`.

Where extended information is needed, use `npm ls --long` (or it's shorthand syntax, `npm la` / `npm ll`). The *extended output* will also include the module description, Git repo link, README and will definitely include **every module** in the tree (some may be skipped with the basic `npm ls`).

Comment: Let me try this out to make sure it works will accept answer after i verify

Comment: This is good, but it doesn't seem to work that well, I have seen a few instances in experimenting with it where it doesn't pick up things that it probably should

Comment: ok, so it looks like you really want "npm la once", this will show an extended list

Comment: @AlexanderMills I've updated my answer with the additional details about `npm la` - is this useful?

Answer (score 1):

The `npm ls <options>` command is definitely what you want.

@Aurora's answer is basically right

Here are the docs for the command:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls

it says

> "When run as ll or la, it shows extended information by default."

So to get a full list of dependencies in your project that depend on x, try:

```
$ npm la x
```

instead of

```
$ npm ls x
```

Answer (score 0):

The page on npmjs.com lists all the dependent packages. In this case there are only 5 of them.

Comment: The OP already seems to know about this, and they don't really want it - they want to do this locally for *their* `package.json`.

Comment: Right, prefer if this were a programmatic solution