# Package.json dependcies issues in a react app using Walmart's Electrode framework

Tags: node.js, npm, walmart-electrode

I'm getting started with Walmart's new React framework called [Electrode](https://github.com/electrode-io/electrode-boilerplate-universal-react-node).

However, I'm having trouble understanding where the project dependencies are defined since I don't see everything in package.json.  I'm running a linter so it's showing me errors saying packages like redux and react are not defined in the dependencies.  However, if I do an npm install, it does install all the packages.  How does npm know to install the other packages?

Here's what's in the package.json - so the other packages like react must be linked or configured or defined elsewhere.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "above-the-fold-only-server-render": "^1.0.2",
    "bluebird": "^3.4.6",
    "electrode-archetype-react-app": "^1.0.0",
    "electrode-csrf-jwt": "^1.0.0",
    "electrode-react-ssr-caching": "^0.1.3",
    "electrode-redux-router-engine": "^1.0.0",
    "electrode-server": "^1.0.0",
    "electrode-static-paths": "^1.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.10.1"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React and Redux are defined in [`electrode-react-ssr-caching`](https://github.com/electrode-io/electrode-react-ssr-caching/blob/master/package.json)'s `package.json`, so they are indirectly dependencies of your project because you depend on `electrode-react-ssr-caching`.

You can see which package causes something to be installed with [`npm ls <package>`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls), e.g. `npm ls react`, which will show the dependency tree for that package (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40825078/view-local-npm-packages-that-depend-on-package-x/40828067#40828067) on a similar question for an example). If you use Yarn, [`yarn why <package>`](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/why) will serve a similar purpose.

Comment: any suggestions on how to accomodate the airbnb eslint error `import/no-extraneous-dependencies` - which states that it should be listed in the dependencies, even though it's included in the sub-dependency?  Should I just ignore that error?  It would be nice to modify that to look at the sub-dependencies as appropriate

Comment: Could you include your `.eslintrc` in the question, so I can take a look?

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey `match-regex` requires that all your files are lower case letters, numbers or dashes (`-`). Is that the case for all your files?

Comment: the error is that the rule was not found - not that it didn't pass the rule

Comment: I installed the filename plugin ` npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-filenames babel-eslint` but it still errors

Comment: I'll move the eslint questions into a new stackoverflow question as it's diverging a bit from the original ask.